# Windows 7 oem installed on 2 pc's?

Tags: windows-7

I know Ms doesn't like this, but is it possible to use a oem key (not a branded oem key) on 1 extra computer?

I bought a new pc with w7, but like to install my girlfriends pc also with the same product key. Is it possible or will I have problems with activation. Imo it shouldn't be a problem because you can allways call ms activation service. In that case, will the other computer (the original one) have problems in the future with updates or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OEM Windows key will activate normally more than once (previous versions anyway, I have not tried with Windows 7).

As you do not seem to be too bothered by your scruples, even if it didn't work I'm sure you could ring up and lie convincingly enough to get the person on the other end of the phone to let you activate your second copy.

So in the short term it will work.

The problem is that every so often Windows gets in touch with Microsoft. As I haven't tried it, I don't know whether Nicrosoft's update thingy will be bothered about two computers using the same key.

I believe that Volume licence keys that appear on the internet soon stop working as they get blocked, but does Microsoft really trawl through the logs of all the machines that connect to check whether a key is used on two machines?

Basically it comes down to how much of a gambler you are. If Microsoft don't block then you have got away with saving a few quid (or whatever), but if your key does get blocked, it won't work on either machine, so you will be forking out for two more licences as well as having a rather angry girlfriend.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work, the activation is tied to the hardware W7 is installed on, it will not activate on the second PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the End User Licence Agreement, you'll see that what you want to do is illegal.

Comment: It may be against the agreement, but not acting in accordance with an agreement is not illegal.

Comment: @Neal: I'm pretty sure it *is* illegal to use software without agreeing to its end user licence agreement, but if it's not, it's at least enough grounds for them to sue you. Besides, breaking digital locks in the United States is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it would work. When you active your copy of Windows the license will be associated with your computer. When she tried to use it, Windows would complain and she would not get updates.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the same key?

This is not a recomendation but anyways, if you install it on 2 different machines, it will be a pirated copy so you're already illegal... just leave one original alone and find a pirated copy for the other! The legal result is better as you'll have only 1 pirated copy instead of 2. :)
But if you want to use free OS... you should consider changing to a real free OS like linux.